# CryptSvc does not exists on my server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, service

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 hosting Sharepoint. In the configuration of Excel Services, I have to set the "Cryptography Service" a dependance of "Claims To Windows Token Service".

However, CryptSvc (Cryptography Service) does not exists on my server. It is not in the service list. Every other machine in my network has this service...

How do I install CryptSvc?

Comment: have you tried -> net start cryptsvc

Comment: Yes, but it does not exists and outputs a message "service name is not valid".